# Executing a string as query in spark data frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am using the following data:

Data for df1:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
k1,i,aa,k
k5,j,ee,l
```

Data for df2:

```
c1,avc2,c3,avc4
k1,a,aa,e
k2,b,bb,f
k3,c,cc,g
k4,d,dd,h
```

I am trying to create a dynamic query string based on the conditions using the code below:

```
val PRIM_CHECK="c1,c3".split(",").toList
val COLUMN_UNCHANGE="c4".split(",").toList
var qb = new ListBuffer[String]()
val df3=df1.join(df2,seq("c1","c3"), "outer")
    for(i<-avro_inp.columns) 
        {
      if(PRIM_CHECK.contains(i))
        {

        }
      else if(COLUMN_UNCHANGE.contains(i)) 
        {
        qb+=""".withColumn(""""+i+"""", when('"""+""+i+""".isNotNull,'"""+i+""").otherwise('av"""+""+i+"""))"""
         }
      else
        {
          qb+=""".withColumn(""""+i+"""", when('av"""+""+i+""".isNull,'"""+i+""").otherwise('av"""+""+i+"""))"""
        }

  }

    val check=qb.mkString
```

However, I want to run the below code

```
df3.+""+check+""+.show()
```

But, I could not run the above code because of the string in the query. Is there any way that I can execute it?

Comment: jesus, this is ugly :)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth i need to create a dynamic query with lot of conditions .I did not find a better way to do.

Comment: but I cannot imagine this to work, you write scala-code in a string, this will not execute

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? Then please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write scala-code in a string and "execute" this string (something like `eval`). Maybe there are hacks to achieve this, but it's definitely not how to write spark/scala code.

I would suggest something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df_result = avro_inp.columns.foldLeft(df3) { case (df, i) =>
  if (PRIM_CHECK.contains(i)) {
    df
  }
  else if (PRIM_CHECK.contains(i)) {
    df.withColumn(i, when(col(i).isNotNull, col(i)).otherwise(col("av" + i)))
  }
  else {
    df.withColumn(i, when(col(i).isNull, col(i)).otherwise(col("av" + i)))
  }
} 

df_result.show
```

or alternatively using a for-loop and `df_result` defined as `var`:

```
var df_result = df3

for (i <- avro_inp.columns) {
  if (PRIM_CHECK.contains(i)) {
  }
  else if (PRIM_CHECK.contains(i)) {
    df_result = df_result.withColumn(i, when(col(i).isNotNull, col(i)).otherwise(col("av" + i)))
  }
  else {
    df_result = df_result.withColumn(i, when(col(i).isNull, col(i)).otherwise(col("av" + i)))
  }
```

}